# Can't create an index catalog in localdb v\11.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, localdb

SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[indexTable] (
    [mapId]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [keyword] VARCHAR (900) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([mapId] ASC)
);

Go
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FTSearch
```

This is the error I get

> Creating [FTSearch]...
>   SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>   Msg 9982, Level 16, State 100, Line 1
>   Cannot use full-text search in user instance.

I am using `localdb\v11.0` that is installed along with visual studio 2012.

Comment: This can be helpful to you to understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845385/sql-error-cannot-use-full-text-search-in-user-instance

Comment: The error message is very clear: **Cannot use full-text search in user instance** - so you **cannot** use full-text search when you're using the `localdb\v11.0` approach - you'll need to use a full-fledged SQL Server instance to use fulltext features

Comment: What Marc said http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/679452/project-juneau-localdb-fulltext-search-restrictions

Comment: lol why do people love to downvote posts on stackoverflow? this is not a noob friendly site at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`localdb\v11.0` does not support fulltext index. I installed `MS SQL Server 2012 express with Advanced Services` and it worked like a charm. I had to create an entirely new database again though it wasn't really much of a problem for me as i just copy pasted all the DDL statements from the my previous database. Also i had to use `'.\SQLEXPRESS'` instead of `'(LocalDb)\v11.0'` as the server name.

During installation if you want to save disk space then only install `Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search` and leave all the other features unchecked.

EDIT:
You can use your old databse. Copy the old database files to a new location preferably to something like `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA`
and run the following sql statement.

```
CREATE DATABASE databaseName 
    ON (FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
    Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\filename.mdf'), -- Main Data File .mdf
    (FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
    Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\filename_log.ldf') -- Log file .ldf

    FOR ATTACH 
GO
```

Comment: Is it still the case in 2024? Also, although it is pretty obvious to me my localdb instance does not support it, do you have any link to a document or an official answer, so, I can track it for future?