# Add SQL Server Express "Advanced" features to LocalDB installed by Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, localdb

I installed VS 2013. It installed SQL Server 2012 Express with LocalDB. That's great, except that I need full-text search, and it didn't install "Advanced Services" (and I didn't see an option during install).

I've downloaded SQL Server 2012 Express w/Advanced Services to add this, but it seems to want to install it on a new instance. Does this sound familiar to you? How did you add SQL Server Advanced Services to your LocalDB installation?

I had the same issue last VS version, and resorted to reinstalling SQL Server then. I apologize for coming to the community with a mundane question, but it vexes me. :)

Here's what I did:

- start the SQL Server Express Advanced install
- choose to modify an existing instance
- check "full-text" under Instance Features / Database Engine Services
- find that the installed instances list is empty at the "Instance Configuration" screen, and it wants to install a new instance

Comment: Just to clarify...   are you mostly wanting to add stuff from "Advanced" to your default instance?  Or are you wanting to run them in LocalDb?

Comment: I want to use Full-Text Search/Index on my LocalDB, and I'd prefer not to install a full-time "instance". I like that (with LocalDB) there's fewer services running on my development laptop when not needed, and that restores occur in my user context so I don't have issues with where my backups are kept. Etc.

Comment: Sure.  While SQL Express should work, it looks like LocalDB is not an option, unless it changed in 2014 ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369730/cant-create-an-index-catalog-in-localdb-v-11-0

Comment: Yes, looks like a duplicate. The other question has a poor title relative to the conditions causing the problem in my case.

Comment: ah...  you can edit it! :)

Comment: Edit the other title you mean? I'm not sure it would be appropriate. You know, that question was about an inability to create a full-text index, with the assumption full-text search was already installed. My question title asked how to install it. Unless the correct answer to his question was actually "full-text isn't installed on your LocalDB" or the correct answer to mine isn't "it can't be installed on LocalDB", I probably shouldn't mirror the titles.

Comment: So I guess they are only kind of duplicates. Same topic. Different scenario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like this cannot be done, unfortunately.

LocalDB is cool, but apparently not all-powerful.
Check out this existing post (among others):

[Can't create an index catalog in localdb v\11.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369730/cant-create-an-index-catalog-in-localdb-v-11-0)

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the issue. A brief comment here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx#fbid=dt2j4yiaS-k ("including SQL Server Express, LocalDB, and SQL Azure. If you need Reporting Services or Full text search, use SQL Server Express") makes me think it hasn't changed in 2014.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that.  But too bad.  It is a great solution for developers, LocalDB.

Answer (score -1):

Check at Windows services, the Instance name (found within braces) for the SQL Server service.

Then,

- start the SQL Server Express Advanced install
- choose to modify an existing instance
- check "full-text" under Instance Features / Database Engine Services
- find that the installed instances list is empty at the "Instance Configuration" screen, and it wants to install a new instance...

At this point,

Manually type the instance name manually that you found at Windows services. (Instance name Case Sensitive though)

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be the crux of the problem. I specifically was trying to avoid installing an instance, and use LocalDB instead. There's a separate Full Text Service (msftesql.exe) that runs and depends on the filter daemon service (fdhost.exe), and neither one of these has a LocalDB equivalent.